# Python Use private methods inside mixin

Tags: python, oop

I have this legacy code: (pseudo)
I want to call the Mixin method to invoke `do`. but for behavior use inside `class` itself, For Parent use `UpdateClass`, for child `DefaultChildClass`.
I try to use the private method `__my_property` but it does not work for `FirstParent` class.

*What I can do in this situation?*

```py
class Mixin:
    my_property = {}

    def do(self, action):
        try:
            return self.my_property.get(action)()
        except:
            return self.default()


class DefaultClass:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')


class UpdateClass:
    def foo(self):
        print('PARENT update')


class DefaultChildClass:
    def foo(self):
        print('CHILD foo')

class FirstParent(Mixin):
    default = DefaultClass
    my_property = {
        'update': UpdateClass
    }

class SecondChild(FirstParent):
    default = DefaultChildClass


p = FirstParent()
method = p.do('update')
method.foo()

cl = SecondChild()
method = cl.do('update')
method.foo()
```

If use `hasattr(self.__class__, 'my_property')` it not help, for child return `True`

Comment: Python doesn't really allow you to make private methods or members. After all, [we're all consenting adults here...](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)